# missing content stream error when indexing file with post.jar

Tags: java, solr

Just installed Solr (4.9.0) for the first time and have it running in Tomcat on RHEL.
I'm attempting to index a folder containing a single xml file using..

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8081/solr/update -jar post.jar *.xml
```

which proceeds as follows...

```
java -Durl=htp://localhost:8081/solr/update -jar post.jar *xml
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url htp://localhost:8081/solr/update using content-type application/xml..
POSTing file 1870_reservations.shp.xml
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to htp://localhost:8081/solr/update..
Time spent: 0:00:00.080
```

However, my solr/update page is showing only....

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">400</int>
    <int name="QTime">0</int>
  </lst>
  <lst name="error">
    <str name="msg">missing content stream</str>
    <int name="code">400</int>
  </lst>
</response>
```

Solr logs also indicate the same.  Any idea why terminal would indicate success while Sol

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: What you mean "However, my solr/update page is showing"? You open the /solr/update url in a browser or what?

Comment: You probably want to look at the admin interface instead and issue a query to your collection.